# Nexus 5 Notification Light Color

Tags: java, android, colors, notifications, light

I am using a Nexus 5 (SDK 4.4.4) and I try to send some notifications with different colors. I tried to test the colors with a simple code :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    NotificationManager notif = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        notif.cancel(1); // clear previous notification
        final Notification notification = new Notification();
        if (i == 0){
            notification.ledARGB = Color.MAGENTA;
        }else if (i == 1){
            notification.ledARGB = Color.BLUE;
        }else if (i == 2){
            notification.ledARGB = Color.CYAN;
        }else if (i == 3){
            notification.ledARGB = Color.GRAY;
        }else if (i == 4){
            notification.ledARGB = Color.GREEN;
        }else if (i == 5){
            notification.ledARGB = Color.RED;
        }else if (i == 6){
            notification.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
        }else if (i == 7){
            notification.ledARGB = Color.YELLOW;
        }
        notification.ledOnMS = 1000;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notif.notify(1, notification);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This code is supposed to send 8 different color notifications. What my mobile actually does, is to replicate 3 colors, blue, red and magenta. The rest of the colors doesn't seems to work.

Of course, the other colors should actually work, as Light Flow application succeeds to send notifications with colors like Green, etc.

What could be the problem here? Is there another code that could actually work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried again to compile this program and I figured out the solution.

For everyone else having the same problem, after I ran the program multiple times, colors started to show and after a restart of my phone this program works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

You can read these: https://developer.android.com/preview/notifications.html , if you will look there, you can see that Google doesn't recommend changing the color of the notification, they recommend to use the transparent color, and I quote :

"**Don't**

Use color to distinguish your app from others. Notification icons should only be a white-on-transparent background image. "

--EDIT--
my mistake, I haven't seen you want to change the led color,

But if you want only change the led color try using codes like : `notification.ledARGB = 0xFFff0000;` for the colors you want.

Comment: I don't think the OP is referring to the icons.

Comment: @MikeM. Yeah I noticed it now and edited my answer :)